# Set viewport size for a browser

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was playing with a webapplication page developed by me using selenium.

Using selenium JavaScriptExecutor I executed following script.

```
executor.executeScript("return window.innerWidth");
executor.executeScript("return window.innerHeight");
```

to my surprise, the so called viewport size came different from Chrome, IE & Firefox.

Chrome: 1366x667
IE: 1366x667
Firefox: 1366x657

Then I realized that for body and main div, right next to body I gave css style width and height as 100% which in turn effects the view port size. As different borwsers are having different size of toolbars and menu, this 100% value changes when actual page is rendered.

So I used window.resizeTo(w,h) for setting a common viewport size. But I realized it doesn't work with modern browsers until and unless window is opened by the same script.

So I used selenium's

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(w,h));
```

yet I am not able to set the common view port size.

Please help to find, is it possible to set common viewport size using selenium?
Do let me know, if you need anymore info.

I executed following line for all browsers:

```
driver.manage().window().getSize();
```

Answer I got is 1382x744

So I believe this about the overall browser window, not only rendering area.
And I got confused that based on the difference of innerWidth how to calculate the browser window's new size?

PS: I have all the **browsers upgraded to latest version** (IE is version 11 as I am on windows 7), **selenium version** I am using is 2.46.x

Comment: Have you tried just passing (w, h) without "new Dimension" ? `driver.manage().window().setSize(w, h);`

Comment: @TomNetzband: Yes I tried, I am confused there little bit. When used get dimension for all browsers, it came as 1382x 744 so I wasn't sure how calculate based on innerWidth and get new dimension for browser window as this dimension affects the entire borwser not only rendering area.

Comment: There are some concepts described in [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

"to my surprise, the so called viewport size came different from Chrome, IE & Firefox."

It should not be surprising that the view port size is different on all browsers, Safari even has a different one as well. When you are calling window.innerHeight it only counts the browsers inner content. So anything outside of it is not counted, the area where you enter your URL is entered is not counted for example. So each browser uses a different amount of maximum height by their tabs, and Global address bar.

When you use driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(w,h)); and set it to 1920x1080 for example then all browsers will be set to that size, but of course they will have different inner height being used.

If you want the entire browser to render as 1920x1080 then I would suggest with

```
using Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
Thread.sleep(250);    
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
```

but I would advise against it, since a more valid test is to use the normal inner height of the browser, since most user do not press F11 and view their content at full screen.